# why java script nested for loop having loops counter name same goes infinetly

Tags: javascript

What will be out put of following code.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
  for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    console.log(i + ' ' + i);
  }}
```

Why it is infinite loop.

Comment: Does it even compile?

Comment: @Ludovic: yeah browser hangs for some time.

Comment: It is infinite, because you overwrite the i variable in the inner loop

Comment: @ozil Ho i didn't see that it's javascript. This language allow too much syntax. Why don't you just use `j` on your second loop? every time you enter the second loop your `i` is reset to 0

Comment: @Ludovic "*This language allow too much syntax*" because other languages do loops so differently? lol

Comment: @epascarello No but redefining the `int i` doesn't compile in most langages

Answer (score 0):

That's because You use `i` two times so every time you enter the second loop you reset your i to 0.

Your code should be:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
  for(var j=0; j<3; j++){
    console.log(i + ' ' + j);
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because each iteration of the outer loop the inner loop is resetting i to 0.  It will never get to 5.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
  // will be 4 here then reset to 0 it will only ever make it to 4 never reach 5.
  for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    console.log(i + ' ' + i);
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you enter your first loop with 0, you reset i back to 0 and when your i becomes 3, you come out of inner loop and enter's outer for 4 and then again reset to 0 and goes in a loop.

You could resolve the issue using two different variables like:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<3; j++) {
        console.log(i + ' ' + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `var` declaration will be hoisted to the top of the scope (i'm not going in to detail why), the code will end up functioning like this:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++
{
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

You think that a far loop creates a new 'code block' (Scope), but it does not.
If ou were to do this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    +function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++
        {

        }
    }();
}
```

Then it would work the wya you think it is going to work now, but you shouldn't. You should just use 2 different variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
1st iteration of loop #1
    starts with i = 0
    1st iteration of loop #2
        starts with i = 0
        ends with i = 1
    2nd iteration of loop #2
        starts with i = 1
        ends with i = 2
    3rd iteration of loop #2
        starts with i = 2
        ends with i = 3
    ends with i = 4
2nd iteration of loop #1
    starts with i = 4
    1st iteration of loop #2
        starts with i = 0
        ends with i = 1
    2nd iteration of loop #2
        starts with i = 1
        ends with i = 2
    3rd iteration of loop #2
        starts with i = 2
        ends with i = 3
    ends with i = 4
3nd iteration of loop #1
    starts with i = 4
    1st iteration of loop #2
        starts with i = 0
        ends with i = 1
    2nd iteration of loop #2
        starts with i = 1
        ends with i = 2
    3rd iteration of loop #2
        starts with i = 2
        ends with i = 3
    ends with i = 4
```

endlessly ;)